# VS2013 file open error in C

Tags: c

i use a vs2013.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){

    FILE *f;
    char fname[] = "17_1.txt";

    if ((f = fopen_s(f,fname, "r+")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "can't open the file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (!feof(f))
    {
        fscanf_s(f, "%d %s %d %d\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "%d %s %d %d \n");
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

but Error   4   error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'f' used
I saw-_-
how must i change?

Comment: You pass `f` as a parameter in the same line that it's being assigned, aka you're using it when it's uninitialized.

Comment: this line: ' while (!feof(f))' the feof function is never set until AFTER an attempt is made to read past the end of a file.  Therefore, it should never be used as a loop control element.

Comment: this line: 'fscanf_s(f, "%d %s %d %d\n");' may (or may not) be successful.  the code should always check the returned value from scanf family of functions to assure the operation was successful.  in this case, because there are 4 conversion factors, the returned value should be 4.  any other returned value indicates an error, or EOF

Comment: if you were to enable all the warnings, when compiling this file, then the compiler would have told you about the problems in the code.

Comment: this line: 'fscanf_s(f, "%d %s %d %d\n");' is saying to input/convert 4 items, but those items are not listed (and the code should be checking the returned value from fscanf_s() to assure the 4 input/convert operations were successful.  Strongly suggest looking up/learning the syntax for the system calls that you use.  Your coding life would be a lot easier.  And again, enabling the compiler warnings would have told you about the problems with the syntax.

Comment: there are only two valid ways to write the main functions; 1) int main(void) (note: the 'void' is optional in most compilers) 2) int main( int argc, char *argv[]) (note: argv can also be written as 'char **argv'  Which ever syntax you use for the main function, it must always end with a return (someINTvalue) where that someINTvalue is usually 0

Comment: this line: 'fprintf(stdout, "%d %s %d %d \n");' says to print 4 items to a stdout, however, those items are not mentioned. The line should look more like: 'fprintf(stdout, "%d %s %d %d \n", intItem, charItem, intItem, intItem);'

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing `fopen_s` and `fopen`. The signature of `fopen_s` is:

```
errno_t fopen_s( 
   FILE** pFile,
   const char *filename,
   const char *mode 
);
```

And the signature of `fopen` is:

```
FILE *fopen(const char *restrict filename, const char *restrict mode);
```

The way you use these two functions respectively is:

```
FILE* f = NULL;
errno_t e;

if ((e = fopen_s(&f, fname, "r+")) != 0)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "can't open the file\n");
}
```

and:

```
if ((f = fopen(fname, "r+")) == NULL)
```

If an error occurs, `fopen` sets `errno`.

Comment: to use errno_t, the code needs to include the <errno.h> header file.